# The will of the Maharsham

Tags: rabbis, techeles

Does anyone know where to find the tzavvah of the Maharsham?

It has been refenced a bunch of times as being a proof that the Maharsham wore techeiles since he asked to be buried with techeiles in his will.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

His son printed it in the beginning of the Maharsham's sefer *Techeiles Mordechai*.

The line about techeiles is in point # 2 and reads as follows:

> הטלית יקחו את הטלית טירקישען בלא העטרה וקשורים בו ציצית עם תכלת

[Here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35914&st=&pgnum=9) is an online source and here is an image of the text highlighted:

[image]